# Do I have EVM Planned Value understood correctly?

Tags: pmp, evm

I am struggling to get all the PMI EVM terminology sorted out.  The last key for me was planned value (PV).

Let say I have a task and my BAC is $100,000 and scheduled for 4 weeks.

2 weeks in I am done 40% of the work and spent $50,000.  So:

- PV: $50,000
- EV: $40,000
- AC: $50,000
- CPI: 0.9 (over budget)
- SPI: 0.9 (behind schedule)

6 weeks out I am done 90% of the work and spent $105,000. So:

- PV: $100,000 (according to the original baseline schedule 4 weeks should have got me $100,000 of EV)
- EV: $90,000
- AC: $105,000
- CPI: 0.86 (more over budget)
- SPI: 0.9 (still behind schedule)

7 weeks out I am done 100% of the work and spent $112,000. So:

- PV: $100,000 (according to the original baseline schedule 4 weeks should have got me $100,000 of EV)
- EV: $100,000
- AC: $112,000
- CPI: 0.90 (over budget)
- SPI: 1.00 (always 1 when complete)

My questions (have I explained / understood this correctly?):

- As soon as you are past your original budgeted timeline for a task your PV = BAC
- PV is the cost you should have accrued if your original schedule was correct (for the same time frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you wrote is correct. Your last bullet my read better as, "PV is the amount of cost accrued at a certain time on the project's timeline."

In your example, your PV was distributed equally across time, i.e., at the end of two weeks you should have 50% of work. Just be aware of you're not already that PV is rarely equal across time.

SPI always approaches 1 as you indicated, which is why EV is not a great schedule control tool. Have a look at Earned Schedule. It is superior to EV to control your schedule.

Comment: I am well aware that PV is not linear and it was clear right away that EVM is not good at the schedule side.  That is a whole other issue.  The CPI and forecasting formulas are pretty good.   I had BAC and PV mixed up original (though they were the same).  It's one of these  moments.